# What is the linux command to copy all ".classpath" files?

Tags: linux

I am looking for a linux command that can copy all ".classpath" for a folder tree and its subfolder, creating a new folder and all the subfolders with the ".classpath" files.

Comment: What did you try? Using [find](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) or coding your small script e.g. in Python should help.

Comment: And why do you ask that? What's the point of coying only `.classpath` files (leaving out the other ones)? Do you have a dozen of them, or a million of them?

Comment: `find /src/directory -type f -name "*.classpath" -print0 | cpio -0dump /dest/directory`...

Answer (score 0):

```
cp `find -name "*.classpath"` destination/
```

Comment: I would use `$(find -name "*.classpath")` which I believe is more readable than your backquotes.

Comment: And this probably don't copy the sub-directories (the OP mention subfolders). You may want `cp -va`

Comment: will this recreate the folder tree?